# Cisco Anyconnect and dynamic split include tunneling on Linux

Tags: linux, anyconnect, split-tunnel

It seems there is some issue with domain-based dynamic split-routing support in the Linux.

In OS X, the routing table contains the routes added by dynamically resolving a domain name to an external IP address. In Linux, the routing table only contains the "static" routes (those set via `X-CSTP-Split-Include`).

The dynamic split tunneling feature is described here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa98/asdm78/vpn/asdm-78-vpn-config/vpn-asdm-setup.html#task_ydq_tbw_tz

When doing `--verbose` here's where the domains are set:

```
<custom-attr>
  <dynamic-split-include-domains>
<![CDATA[example.com,]]></dynamic-split-include-domains>
</custom-attr>
```

It was introduced in the version 4.6

[image]

Comment: Apparently, not supported on Linux at all. See https://github.com/dlenski/vpn-slice/issues/68